# HTTP2 unknown or unsupported SETTINGS identifier MUST be ignored

Tags: http2

From [RFC7540](http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#SETTINGS) SETTINGS section:

> An endpoint that receives a SETTINGS frame with any unknown or unsupported identifier MUST ignore that setting.

Does this is intended to be applied on the single setting, or all settings frame must be ignored if there is any unknown or unsupported identified ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a single setting! A frame can contain multiple settings. The idea is that further extensions to HTTP/2 can introduce new settings, but they should work in such a way that "old implementations" would work even if they don't support the extension. There is also an acknowledgement mechanism, that should be used to *not acknowledge* any settings that were ignored.